# ufw rule supposed to block traffic but iptables allows it

Tags: iptables, http, https, ufw

As a test I wanted to temporarily block access to my website. So, I deleted http/https rules using `ufw delete` command. ufw is set to default deny incoming. The only remaining rule is the one allowing me to SSH into my machine.

Unfortunately, I still can access my website. Apparently, there is a conflict with iptables:

```bash
# ufw status verbose
Status: active
Logging: on (low)
Default: deny (incoming), allow (outgoing), disabled (routed)
New profiles: skip

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
16000/tcp                  ALLOW IN    183.31.121.0/24

# iptables -L -n | grep 443
ufw-http   tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:443

# cat /etc/iptables.up.rules | grep 443
-A ufw-before-input -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j ufw-http
```

How come I can still access my website? Did ufw mismanaged iptables?

Note: I no longer use Docker -> I have disabled it and its socket too, I also flushed/reloaded iptables (no mention of Docker anymore) and removed the network interfaces set by Docker.

Could have these iptables rules been set by Docker when I used it? If so, I guess I should remove them manually.

Comment: can you show the output of `ufw status`

Comment: Updated. Thank you.

Comment: so, UFW has nothing to do with the rule in `/etc/iptables.up.rules` - perhaps a rule there is allowing web traffic before the rules added by ufw can block it?

Comment: I just noticed I have, in the past, added some rules for DDOS protections in the `before.rules` config file. Among other things, I see `-A ufw-before-input -p tcp --dport 443  -j ufw-http` in that file… Is it possible to keep that `before.rules` file intact while temporary removing that rule in iptables when I do `ufw delete 80,443/tcp`? Then, afterwards `ufw reload` to put that rule back into iptables while allowing http/https access? Thank you.

Comment: OK, I removed the iptables rules set by UFW's `before.rules` file: `iptables -D ufw-before-input -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j ufw-http; iptables -D ufw-before-input -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ufw-http`. And then, I no longer have access to my site. Just need to do `ufw reload` to gain access back to the site.